# How to resolve "Failed to launch 'example://' because the scheme does not have a registered handler."?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing a React Native project and using Deep Linking for a section. When a specified website is opened in the app, this causes the app be opened. For the website, I'm using Next.js.

But my problem is, when the button in the website is clicked, the app is not opened and the browser throws this error:

```bash
Failed to launch 'example://' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.
```

I've examined `router.push()` and `window.location.replace()` but none of the above worked.

How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Link` component in Next.js and added `ref` prop to the `a` tag within. Using `setTimeout`, `useEffect` and the `ref` above, I implemented this:

```js
const [transId, setTransId] = useState<string | null>(null);
const [idGet, setIdGet] = useState<string | null>(null);
const returnToAppLink = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  let timeoutTimer: any;

  if (transId && idGet && returnToAppLink && returnToAppLink.current) {
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      returnToAppLink.current?.click();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
}, [transId, idGet, returnToAppLink]);
```